# How can I replace a variable in my Symfony 4 function?

Tags: php, function, symfony, variables, controller

I created a function in my Controller that is working with the Entity `Members`. What I want to do now is make the function flexible, so that I can use it for all my other entities too. The name of the entity should therefore be dependent on the slug. So in this case the `slug = members`:

```
/**
  * @Route("/pages/{slug}/forms", name="forms", methods={"POST", "GET"})
  */

  public function form($slug, Request $request){
     $item = new Members();    
     $item= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Members::class)->find($id);
 }
```

So what I am trying to do is replace the entityname with the slug:

```
/**
  * @Route("/pages/{slug}/forms", name="forms", methods={"POST", "GET"})
  */

  public function form($slug, Request $request){
     $item = new $slug();    
     $item= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($slug::class)->find($id);
 }
```

But I get an error message:

> Attempted to load class "members" from the global namespace. Did you
>   forget a "use" statement?

Does this has something to do with the uppercase/lowercase of the slug?

Comment: Of course. Classes are case sensitive. You need a use for all Classes used to import them to your Namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All our entities are probably in something like `src\Entity`, and depending how you set up each entity will be in some namespace or other, like `App\Entity`.

Also, members in your slug is in lowercase, but your class begins with a captital however.

All you need to do is make sure `members` becomes `Members`, and where you say

`$item = new $slug()`

You probably want:

```
$fullClassName = 'App\\Entity\\' . ucwords($slug);
$item = new $fullClassName()`
```

Give it a try and let me know how you get on!

Comment: @Jarla: What delboy1978uk suggested should work, but make sure you apply proper input sanitization so some sensitive data could not leak (if any)

Comment: One question: I tried to use the variable also here `$item= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($fullClassName::class)->find($id);` but then I get the error message `Compile Error: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch`